# How to add an attribute to a node-taxonomy relationship?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I'll try to explain my problem through an example ...

I have to do a recipe site with Drupal. I have an *ingredient* taxonomy and for each recipe I have to assign taxonomy and a value.

Example: 4 Eggs, where 'Eggs' is a taxonomy term.

Is there some module that can help me with this?

Comment: Which Drupal ? 6/7

Comment: I do not install Drupal yet.. in which is much easyer do something like this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here.  Adding taxonomy terms to nodes is a basic feature available in both Drupal 6 and 7.  What is it specifically that you want to do?

Comment: I want to add an argument to taxonomy/node relation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you might want to use the [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module (Drupal 7 only):

> Relation is an API module and storage model for both simple and the most complex relations between entities. The module can handle both directional and symmetrical relations very well.
>
> Relations are entities and can therefore have fields. This makes Relation the most flexible and powerful relation model out there.

You could create a relationship entity with a 'Value' field (to store e.g. the number of eggs) and then use that entity as a relationship field to link your nodes and taxonomy terms.